# Go cannot connect to Mongo container when using docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, go

I would like to run 3 services:

1. My Go program which will connect to MongoDB in another container
2. Mongo
3. Mongo Express

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    image: test-go-docker
    environment:
      - MONGO_HST=mongo
      - MONGO_PRT=27018

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
    - 27018:27017
    volumes:
    - /data/db

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
    - 8081:8081
```

As you can see, my Mongo database is mapped to port 217018, with the network name mongo.

My Golang program will take in the hostname and port through environment variables (MONGO_HST and MONGO_PRT). Here's my Go program:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"
)

type MyData struct {
    Name string
    Text string
}

func viewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello world!")
}

func main() {
    mongoURI := "mongodb://" + os.Getenv("MONGO_HST") + ":" + os.Getenv("MONGO_PRT") + "/"
    client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI(mongoURI))
    must(err)

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 20*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    err = client.Connect(ctx)

    collection := client.Database("test_db").Collection("test_collection")
    data := MyData{
        Name: "testing...",
        Text: "Hello world",
    }

    _, err =collection.InsertOne(context.Background(), data)
    must(err)

    // Serve the page
    http.HandleFunc("/", viewHandler)
    err = http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
    must(err)
}

func must(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Some error...")
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

After I run docker-compose, checking the logs for my Go container would result in the following message:

```
Some error...
panic: server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: mongo:27018, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() : dial tcp 172.25.0.4:27018: connect: connection refused }, ] }

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.must(0xccfce0, 0xc0002dd000)
        /go/src/my_app/cmd/main.go:50 +0xae
main.main()
        /go/src/my_app/cmd/main.go:39 +0x35d
```

From the log, I can see that Go was trying to connect to the following address: mongo:27018, which is in fact what I would like to see.

Running `docker ps`, I also can see that my 2 containers mongo, mongo-express are running:

```
29533908c7fc   mongo           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   50 minutes ago   Up 50 minutes   0.0.0.0:27018->27017/tcp   go-with-docker_mongo_1
f4789b54ddbd   mongo-express   "tini -- /docker-ent…"   50 minutes ago   Up 50 minutes   0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp     go-with-docker_mongo-express_1
```

Any ideas? Much appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connections between containers ignore `ports:`.  Use the standard port for the target container, in this case the standard MongoDB port 27017.

```yaml
services:
  app:
    environment:
      - MONGO_PRT=27017 # the standard port

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    # ports:            # not used for connections between containers
    # - 27018:27017     # only from outside Docker
```

[Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation says a little more.